# Do I need a special seed or type of tree for growing a bonsai tree?

Tags: trees, seeds, bonsai

I want to grow a bonsai tree. Do I need a special type of seed or tree for me to be able to grow it as a bonsai tree?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need a special type of seed or tree for it to be able to be grown as a bonsai. Bonsai trees are just normal trees that are kept from growing big.

There are certain types of trees that grow better as bonsai trees and are easier to keep small (and in a small pot) than others. These are however, still normal trees and not some special mini species of the tree.

When looking to buy seeds or saplings you can simply buy the type of tree you plan to grow. You do not need to buy a special 'bonsai' or 'mini' species of the tree.

Comment: Excellent answer TheWhiteAfrican...I would add that I would choose a species with the smallest leaves possible.  That gives the illusion that the leaves belong to the tiny trunk...as in models.  And I will add, one should definitely take a hands on class at least once, from a master.  To do Bonsai off the internet is setting oneself up for heartbreak.  As a humongous master gardener, I would not try this without lessons from the best master possible even if it entailed learning their language, grins!!

Comment: I am a bonsai hobbyist. Lessons from a master might be nice but iare not necessary. There are abundant resources on the web such as the artcles at evergreengardenworks.com [link](http://evergreengardenworks.com/articles.htm) and forums like BonsaiNut.com [link](http://bonsainut.com) to name two. It is not a 'pass time' for those who fear failure, It is a fun thing to do for those who like to dive in and learn by doing. Masters will only speed learning the artistry of bonsai, if you can afford it.

Comment: Grins, I agree with your dive in and either learn by doing or drown approach!!  The masters I've worked with had no translater and learning was all tactile and visual.  Broke my heart to lose a 15 year old baby I tried...but waiting for retirement when one has a better attention span might help me to take this up again.  I love the 'groves'.